# How do I find the danger level of areas?

Tags: octopath-traveler

I am closing in on my last hero to join my party, so will start levelling characters ready for Chapter 2.

As I will need to match Danger Levels to various character levels, how can I find specific areas and their danger level? To provide enough of a challenge to get quicker levelling.

Is it simply a matter of noting the danger levels as I move around the map? Or are specific places tougher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an interactive map available at http://www.octopathtravelmap.com/ which lists the danger levels of areas.

In case the link goes stale, the general rule of thumb is that the danger level increases the further you are from the center of the map.